# Why Is SwashBuckle AddSwaggerGen CustomSchemaIds not used in generating the swagger.json and Swagger UI?

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I am attempting to try to modify/map some of the schema types in an open api document.  When I run this ASPNET Web API, I get the Swagger UI with the schemas at the bottom.  But, it does not use the `options.CustomSchemaIds(CustomSchemaGenerator.GetCustomSchemaId)` configuration.  (It does not hit any breakpoint, nor do the returned results affect the output).

Why would it not use this configuration?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.CustomSchemaIds(CustomSchemaGenerator.GetCustomSchemaId);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

public static class CustomSchemaGenerator
{
    public static string GetCustomSchemaId(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }

        if (type.ToString().Contains("ListResponse"))
        {
            Debug.Write(type.ToString());
        }
        return type.ToString();
    }
```

}